# How can I beat the Guardian of Yendor?

Tags: unexplored

I can damage him, so going by "if it bleeds, we can kill it", I'm assuming I can finish it off. But both times I've tried to fight the thing I ended up permastunned (as in, I was stunned and the bar never decreased, so I stayed stunned forever... not he just kept hitting me and restunning before the stun ran out). Especially frustrating since I had the ring of Stone Skin on, which is supposed to make me immune to stuns. I'm unsure if this is a bug or a boss mechanic.

How exactly does the guardian work? I noticed when I shot arrows at him they bounced off and seemed to come back at me. Did I stun myself because my weapon has stun on it, and therefore it reflected back at me, or does the guy just stun anyway?

Given that it usually takes me two hours to get to him, and dying to him means losing the game, I haven't wanted to experiment much. I just book it for the staircase. Basically I'm curious what the guardian's abilities are and what a strategy would be for beating him. Is there anything worthwhile for doing so?

Comment: I can't even find the game you're talking about. It sounds like some kind of nethack clone, but nothing comes up in search. Link?

Comment: Yeah, my bad. It's [Unexplored](http://store.steampowered.com/app/506870/), not Undiscovered. Fixed the tag.

Answer (score 4):

The Guardian is easily defeated if you have at least a couple of powerful magic wands. Namely, a +5 Staff of Fireballs, +5 Staff of Lightning, or even the Staff of Fiery Doom are very effective against it. Also, the Guardian is not immune to poison. If you manage to find an item that makes you immune to poison, you can severely weaken the Guardian by hiding in a small room (with no open flames) and filling it with poison gas repeatedly. The Guardian will keep reappearing in that room looking for you, taking poison damage all the while.

Another way is to hide on a level with lots of spiky walls. The Guardian will repeatedly teleport into or next to the spikes, taking damage.

Going toe-to-toe in melee combat is usually inadvisable. However, if you make a +5 Staff of Life Steal (by taking the Necromancer's staff & using 2 enchant scrolls on it,) you can repeatedly hit the Guardian with a powerful weapon, (taking equal damage in the process) and heal up with the staff.

Be sure to have at least a few Scrolls of Recharge as well!

Bows were once effective, yet updates seem to have added arrows to the Guardian's many immunities.

Now get back down there & take the bastard down! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You don't defeat him, you grab the amulet and run all the way back to start, that's how you win the game